# Can I setup JavaScript to immediately start polling a connected gamepad?

Tags: javascript, browser, dom-events, hid, gamepad

As it's documented in the Mozilla Docs for the JavaScript [GamePad API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Gamepad_API/Using_the_Gamepad_API), the browser only really starts catching events from the gamepad once the user interacts with the pad in some way (i.e. presses a button or moves an axis). Then the browser will start catching the events at the cost of ignoring the first event.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening such that the very first event of the gamepad is also caught? Is it also possible to grab the state of the gamepad before any interaction to capture the "starting state/configuration" that would drive initial webpage organization?

Comment: As a security measure, the user has to interact with the gamepad controller in some way once the page has loaded. This is a browser security feature and not something you can get around. It's possible for you to know once a gamepad has actually been connected and sending events to your script, so I'd wait to have your game start until you've detected a connected gamepad.

Comment: I see. I was worried that would be the case. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

How are you reading gamepad state? I'm not sure what you mean by "at the cost of ignoring the first event." Gamepad API doesn't generate events for button or axis inputs, you have to poll navigator.getGamepads() to get new data.

You can get the initial state when the gamepad is first exposed to the page by registering a gamepadconnected listener. The gamepadconnected event has a gamepad property that holds the current gamepad state:

```
window.addEventListener('gamepadconnected', e => {
  // e.gamepad is the current state when the gamepad was connected.
  console.log(e.gamepad.buttons[0].value);
});
```